# How to check if a set of characters are contained in a character array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, character

This is my first question here at stackoverflow. I hope to find what i'm looking for. I'm trying to find a way to check if a group of characters belong to an array. This was asked in class and I tried to figure it out, but got nothing in the output.

Create an array of 10 characters, containing letter from a to j.
Check if the array contains a, b, c character values.
If so,let the user enter a name, and if the entered name is TEST
display TEST 5 times.

I know there's something wrong with the if statement. Please advise! thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string name;
    char arr[10] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        if ((arr[x] == 'a') && (arr[x] == 'b') && (arr[x] == 'c'))
        {
            cout << "Enter a name" << endl;
            cin >> name;
            if (name == "TEST")
                for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
                    cout << "TEST" << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for bold text, we're not blind (I'd guess most of us). Better put efforts on formatting your code correctly, and explain what exactly goes wrong with it. Also how do you consider this condition `if ((arr[x] == 'a') && (arr[x] == 'b') && (arr[x] == 'c'))` ever becoming true? Did you mean to use logical or (`||`) actually?

Comment: I recommend the `std::string` data type and some of it's methods like `find` and `substr`.

Comment: Hi πάντα ῥεῖ. Well, I'm still not used to the formatting of stackoverflow, that's it. I got the answer here on stackoverflow. this can be solved using three boolean variables. bool b1 = false;
 bool b2 = false;
 bool b3 = false;
 for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
 {
  if (arr[x] == 'a')
  {
   b1 = true;
  }
  if (arr[x] == 'b')
  {
   b2 = true;
  }
  if (arr[x] == 'c')
  {
   b3 = true;
  }                                                                                                       }
 if ((b1 == true) && (b2 == true) && (b3 == true))
 {
  cout << "Enter a name" << endl;

Comment: Can you explain what kind of a letter is both 'a', 'b', and 'c' at the same time? Because that's what your if() statement literally (pun not intended) checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code snippet for your understanding:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    char arr[10] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };

    bool found_a = false;
    bool found_b = false;
    bool found_c = false;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        if( arr[x] == 'a' ) {
            found_a = true;
        } else if( arr[x] == 'b' ) {
            found_b = true;
        } else if( arr[x] == 'c' ) {
            found_c = true;
        }

        if(found_a == true && found_b == true && found_c == true) {
            cout << "Enter a name" << endl;
            cin >> name;
            if (name == "TEST") {
                for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
                    cout << "TEST" << endl;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```